# Div change height when user click content JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with rising height of div element. To see that problem you have to insert new element **"legal case box"**. Then you have to click to **top right div** /  **top left div**. You can type 1 letter and then delete it (or just set focus and remove it) -> you can see to rising of div element. I don't understand why it happens. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks!

I also notice that it happens if doesn't comment `innerDiv1.setAttribute("data-text", "Full Name of the Case");`

**It problem appears in Safari browser.**

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content:attr(data-text)
}
.boxed {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.divTable {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
.divRow {
    display:table-row;
}
.divCell {
    display:table-cell;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script>
    function insert(elem) {
        document.getElementById("mainDiv").focus();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

        range.insertNode(elem);
    }

    function legalCaseBox() {
        var innerDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
        innerDiv1.contentEditable = 'true';
        innerDiv1.style.minWidth = '50pt';
        innerDiv1.style.minHeight = '50pt';
        innerDiv1.classList.add('divCell');
       //innerDiv1.setAttribute("data-text", "Full Name of the Case");

        var innerDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
        innerDiv2.contentEditable = 'true';
        innerDiv2.style.minWidth = '50pt';
        innerDiv2.style.minHeight = '50pt';
        innerDiv2.classList.add('divCell');
        innerDiv2.setAttribute("data-text", "Year");

        var firstDiv = document.createElement('div');
        firstDiv.contentEditable = 'false';
        firstDiv.classList.add('divTable');

        var rowDiv = document.createElement('div');
        rowDiv.classList.add('divRow');
        rowDiv.appendChild(innerDiv1);
        rowDiv.appendChild(innerDiv2);

        firstDiv.appendChild(rowDiv);

        var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
        secondDiv.style.minWidth = '150pt';
        secondDiv.style.minHeight = '80pt';
        secondDiv.contentEditable = 'true';
        secondDiv.classList.add('boxed');
        secondDiv.setAttribute("data-text", "Case summary");

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.contentEditable = 'false';
        div.classList.add('inline');
        div.classList.add('boxed');
        div.appendChild(firstDiv);
        div.appendChild(secondDiv);

        insert(div);
    }
</script>
<body id="main" spellcheck="false">
    <button onclick="legalCaseBox()">legalCaseBox</button>
    <div id="mainDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfysfz6k/3/

Comment: People let people Live... When sm1 creates fiddle, there come's someone saying to use SO Code snippet, when that is done someone needs fiddle..

Comment: I get an error when trying to run your code: ´IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index´ (Chrome 42)

Comment: I am getting Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index. error

Comment: @Arun i added focus function, try now : )

Answer (score 0):

**Observation**
 The first div is empty so its height is less and `year` div has some height greater than first div, so when click on first div it is not getting minimized as you the year div has some minimum height due to text. 
when you click on year div , the first div is empty and has lesser height so until you enter something your year div is minimized.

If you don't want to umcomment the above line then try adding `height` to each div

Comment: Thank you for answer! I don't want to uncomment the line, but i also don't want to have static height of div elements. I want to height changes dynamically. Can you help me? I really don't know how to fix this right.

Comment: just  add the height to `.divTable` . like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljhsqdcb/). enter some data and see, the height of div changes. If this helped then i'll update my post

Comment: Whatever i can click on second div then click on another area and then click on second div again. I see empty div with big height. Sorry for my stupid, but i really don't understand : (

Comment: thats expected. and what you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: As you can see, when i click on first div (top left div) and then click on another area div doesn't rise, but second div (top right) rises in that case. Difference between them it's "placeholder" (innerDiv1.setAttribute("data-text", "Full Name of the Case")). So i want to second div doesn't rise when i set focus on/off on it like first div. I hope you understand what i want.

Comment: i understood what you want. i followed want you said, but i didn't see the second top right div raising. which browser are you using ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91623/discussion-between-j-santosh-and-nikita-ermolenko).